# Inviscid Burgers' equation (Verify the solution)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

From the inviscid Burgers' equation on $\mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty),$ $$u_t + uu_x = 0,$$ for any differentiable function $f$, $v(x,t) = f(x-ut)$ is an implicit solution to the equation.

So I want to verify that $v_t + vv_x = 0.$ Since $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x-ut) = f'(x-ut) (0 - (u+tu_t)) = -(u(x,t) + tu_t(x,t))f'(x-ut)$$ and $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-ut) = f'(x-ut)(1-tu_x) = f'(x-ut)(1 - tu_x(x,t)),$$ $$v_t + vv_x = -(u+tu_t)f'(x-ut) + f(x-ut)(1-tu_x)f'(x-ut).$$

I do not see why $v(x,t)$ is the solution to the equation ?

Comment: You are aware that $v=u$ resp. that you should write the implicit equation as $v=f(x-vt)$?

Comment: Why $v = u$ ? Basically, it mentioned in the book that for any differentiable function $f$, $f(x-ut)$ is the solution. So I set $v$ to be that function, and I want to show the above.

Comment: So for some reasons, I need to really call $f(x-ut)$ by $u(x,t)$ ? That is, $u(x,t) = f(x-ut)$ satisfied $u_t+uu_x = 0.$ I I will accept this as explanation then. Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what "implicit" means in "implicit solution"? It means that $u(x,t)=f(x-tu(x,t))$ is not an explicit formula for $u$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there may be a typo in the problem you're being asked to solve. An implicit solution is $u(x, t) = f(x-ut)$. To see why that's the case, take derivatives, as you did:

$$u_t = -f'(x-ut)(u+tu_t) \implies u_t = -\frac{u f'(x-ut)}{1+tf'(u-xt)},$$
$$u_x = f'(x-ut)(1-tu_x) \implies u_x = \frac{f'(x-ut)}{1+tf'(u-xt)}.$$

So we have $u_t + uu_x = 0$, as required.